# how to get data from last day and actual timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm brand new to Pine Script and programming and want to write a simple indicator, but it seems harder than expected.

I'm trying to get data from last day with request.security() and data from current time frame at the same time, but I can't do it.

I want to draw lines on the high and low from the last day and plotshape when these lines are broken.

How can I do this? Here is my written code which is 100% wrong.

```
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © roddysweg

//@version=5
indicator("My Test allert1", overlay = true)

[d_high, d_low] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",[high[0],low[0]])

newDay = ta.change(time('D'))
var line LastHigh = na
var line LastLow = na


if newDay
    LastHigh := line.new(bar_index, d_high, bar_index+1, d_high)
    LastLow := line.new(bar_index, d_low, bar_index+1, d_low)
    
LastHigh.set_x2(bar_index)
LastLow.set_x2(bar_index)



[chart_high, chart_low, chart_open, chart_close] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, [high, low, open, close])

Cond1 = chart_close > LastHigh
Cond2 = chart_open <= LastLow
BreakLine1 = Cond1 and Cond2
plotshape(BreakLine1, 'Break', shape.arrowup, location.abovebar, color.green, 0, 'Breaking\nLine', textcolor = color.green)
```

> The `condition` parameter of the `if` accepts a 'bool' argument. To avoid potential unexpected results, pass a 'bool' value or expression to this parameter.

> Cannot call 'operator <=' with argument 'expr1'='LastLow'. An argument of 'literal string' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code as a standard sample. The higher timeframe is variable and you can change it easily, I defined an EMA to get long/short cross conditions, you can change the other timeframe signal too, in the below code I get hlc3, but there isn't any limitation, you can change it to close/high/low/hl2 ....

```
//@version=5
indicator("Sample8",overlay=true,max_bars_back=50)

_higher_timeframe = input.timeframe('60', "Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame")  
_higher_tf_signal = hlc3
indexCurrTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1
_security_result = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _higher_timeframe, _higher_tf_signal ,lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)[indexCurrTF] 

//Moving Average
_EMA = ta.ema(close,5)
plot(_security_result,title="HLC3",color=color.rgb(239, 255, 59),linewidth=2,style=plot.style_line)
plot(_EMA,title="EMA",color=color.rgb(29, 93, 255),linewidth=4,style=plot.style_line)

//Short longs Conditions
long_condition = ta.crossover(_EMA,_security_result)
sell_condition = ta.crossunder(_EMA,_security_result)

plotshape(long_condition ,color =color.rgb(19, 52, 238) ,size=size.small,style = shape.triangleup,location = location.belowbar)
plotshape(sell_condition ,color =color.rgb(226, 49, 49) ,size=size.small,style = shape.triangledown,location = location.abovebar)
```